# Xaml hyperlink element with Tag property

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

I'm currently adding `<hyperlink />` 's inside a TextBlock element in my Windows Store Runtime app (Xaml, C#), However these hyperlinks are navigating internally so the NavigateUri is useless to me.

I can add a Click event handler which navigates to the correct page when the hyperlink is clicked, but I also need to pass a parameter (string) to the new page unique to the hyperlink.

This would be perfect if it had a Tag Element as I could store the parameter inside the Tag property and pass that in on navigation. However hyperlink class has no such property.

What element could I use in its place? bearing in mind this goes inline with the rest of the text. Or is there away to pass this information to the Click handler without using the Tag property?

Comment: Why not add something to the query string for the Urls?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to subclass `Hyperlink` and add the required property as well as internally handle the click event in the newly derived class.

If you'd rather avoid that - you can implement and [attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh701833.aspx) (just like `Grid.Row`) that has the link information.